# How to update a json file with express, axios and react?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have been using json-server which has been brilliant in setting up my app to get data.
I now want to do a little bit more with it so I am using express so that I can do some "backend logic" when I need to.

but I am struggling on how to use a json data file

so far I have this:

```
app.get("/basket", function(req, res) {
  var basket = [
    {name: 'football', id:'spo-001', category: 'sport', quantity: 1, price: 80},
    {name: 'cricket ball', id:'spo-002', category: 'sport', quantity: 1, price: 10},
    {name: 'atlas', id:'geo-001', category: 'geog', quantity: 1, price: 50}
  ]
  res.status(200).send(basket);
})
```

so when I hit this route I can get the basket data back, then inside my react/redux app, I increase the quantity of one of them and then immediately updated the backend (json-server), so when I refreshed the page, my data persisted.

however, I'm a bit lost how to use a JSON file that with express. I've just found this `server.use('/api', jsonServer.router('db.json'));`

how can I then use that json data inside here like this:

```
app.get("/basket", function(req, res) {

  res.status(200).send(sendBackTheDataFromTheJsonFile);
})
```

Comment: What logic are you not able to extend using `jsonServer`?

Comment: im not able to get the json file from json server into my express file. i want to fe => make request => express server does calculation => queries json => returns json => frontend renders

Comment: You can add custom logic in jsonServer routes

Answer (score 1):

Use the fs module to read the json file.

```
const fs = require('fs');


app.get("/basket", function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('db.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
     let dbData = JSON.parse(data);
     res.status(200).send(dbData);

  });
})
```

If you want to update an entry do something similar to this:

```
 app.put("/basket", function(req, res) {
      fs.readFile('db.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
         let dbData = JSON.parse(data);
         // Update data here.
         // You will have to figure out how to do it yourself
         // After you have update the entry, write the entire array back to the json file.
         updatedJSONData = JSON.stringify(dbData)
         fs.writeFile('db.json', json, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // Do something here
             res.status(200).send("Basket was updated");

         } );

      });
    })
```

In your axios method you must specify the url as `/basket` and the method should be `put`

Comment: but where are you using the json-server data here?

Comment: Aren't you using express?

Comment: haha yeh you're right. it's saying that data is undefined on the last line?

Comment: but obj is what im expecting?

Comment: its undefined still. but it's the correct thing inside??

Comment: @RedBaron okay now it should. work. updated my answer

Comment: ok this looks good, thanks. and if i want to go the other way, I can make a post request and how would I update the json file?

Comment: I get 404 not found when I try to make post with axios but when i hit the route in my url, it is there :/

Comment: @RedBaron added a put method

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring in the .json file into the application and then send what you attach it to back in the response. `const data = require('db.json')` and then `res.status(200).send(data)`

Using `fs` is probably a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success with the express static middleware.

```
app.use(express.static('basket'))
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html